# Optimal placement of points inside a disk

Tags: calculus, probability, geometry

Given the unit disk centered at origin, take a random point $x$ within the disk. Find two points $a$, $b$ on the disk such that $E(Y)$, the expected value of the random variable Y, is minimized for $Y = \min(distance(x,a),distance(x,b))$.

Comment: I suppose this is the same as finding center of gravity of a semi-disc.